# In Grails how do I access the hibernate session inside of a domain class static method?

Tags: hibernate, grails, sessionfactory

I've read various articles on the web, but they seem rather scattered on this point.  Exactly what do I need to do in my configuration and in my method to get the hibernate session.  I'm trying to make some direct sql calls for stored procedures.  I have a large code base that I am porting from Ruby with lots of static methods and stored procedure calls.  If I need to use the sessionFactory, then how to I get access to it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From a static method you can pull the sessionFactory bean from the application context:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH
...
def ctx = AH.application.mainContext
def sessionFactory = ctx.sessionFactory
def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
```

Comment: ApplicationHolder is now deprecated, is there an update methodology for this?

Comment: `import grails.util.Holders` will import the non deprecated static Holder and then `Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.sessionFactory` will give you a handle on the sessionFactory.

Comment: Avoid `Holders`. Just because it's not deprecated doesn't mean you should use it. In fact, it has _exactly_ the same problems that `ApplicationHolder` and the others had, and should also be deprecated and removed. If all you're looking for is the current Hibernate session, `withSession` is the best option (see the answer from @michal-zmuda)

Answer (score 24):

If it's in a service or controller, you just need to declare sessionFactory

> def sessionFactory

to have it injected.   After that you can refer to

```
sessionFactory.currentSession
```

to use it.

Check out hibernate-filter plugin (file HibernateFilterGrailsPlugin.groovy) for how to inject a bunch of methods that use the session.

Comment: I'm specifically looking how to get it from a domain class static method.  I don't want to have to get the session from the controller and pass it into the methods.  That's so 1990s'

Comment: I tried this with Grails 2.1 and the session factory doesn't seem to be injected into the service. Burt's method above seems to still work.

Comment: I tried with grails 2.4.4 and its not being injected.

Comment: Works perfectly in Grails 3.2.2.

Answer (score 15):

You can use *withSession*

```
Book.withSession { session ->
    session.clear()
}
```

[More info](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withSession.html)

Comment: This doesn't appear to give you the full Hibernate session, instead it's a Grails session, which is missing a few methods (`createSQLQuery ` for example)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a comment full of truth. The session isn't a "Grails" session, it's a Hibernate session. It's easy enough to determine; replace `session.clear()` with `println session.getClass().name` and you're highly likely to see `org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl` in the output